# Find date/financial quarter in file name (yyyy/mm/dd) then change date in file name to yyyy/mm/dd + 3 months

Tags: python

Problem: there are 100+ tables to UNION ALL. The only difference in the name is the date. Instead of writing 100+ code blocks and only changing the date, it makes more sense to write a python script to output the sql code:

Our SQL query, querying one table (i.e. one financial quarter):

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT
      PCR.repdte
      FROM 
      All_Reports_19921231_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
      PCR) AS Quarter,
  (SELECT 
      Round(AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr))
      FROM 
      All_Reports_19921231_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
      PCR) AS NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
  (SELECT sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int))
      FROM 
     'All_Reports_19921231_Deposits_Based_on_the_Dollars250,000
     _Reporting_Threshold' AS LD) AS 
     DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k
```

The naming convention of each file name includes the date (financial quarter)

```
All_Reports_19921231_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios
All_Reports_19921231_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios
All_Reports_19921231_Deposits_Based_on_the_Dollars250,000
_Reporting_Threshold
```

We want to query all financial quarters including 19921231 to the present

```
    19921231
    19930331
    19930630 
    19930930
    19931231
    19940331
    19940630
    19940930
    19941231
    19950331
    19950630
    19950930
    19951231
     …..
     ….
    20180930
```

The script will:

```
Step one:  find the yyyy/mm/dd in the file name (e.g. 19921231)

Step two:  copy the query

Step three: change the yyyy/mm/dd in the copied file name(s)
IF 1231 change to “+1”0331   (e.g. 19921231 to 19930331)
IF 0331 change to 0630       (e.g. 19930331 to 19930630)
IF 0630 change to 0930       (e.g. 19930630 to 19930930)
IF 0930 change to 1231       (e.g. 19930930 to 19931231)
IF 1231 change to +1 0331    (e.g. 19931231 to 19940331)
…..
…..
…..
IF 91231 change to 00331  (e.g. 19991231 to 20000331)
….
IF 91231 change to 0031 (e.g. 20091231 to 20100331) 

Step four: print new code block after UNION ALL 
Step five: repeat step three
Step six: repeat step four
```

The input would be a single financial quarter, (see above code block), with the output being, that code block repeated 100+ times, with only the yyyy/mm/dd changed in each file name.  Each code block will be joined with a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT
      PCR.repdte
      FROM 
      All_Reports_19921231_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
      PCR) AS Quarter,
  (SELECT 
      Round(AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr))
      FROM 
      All_Reports_19921231_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
      PCR) AS NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
 (SELECT sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int))
      FROM 
     'All_Reports_19921231_Deposits_Based_on_the_Dollars250,000
      _Reporting_Threshold' AS LD) AS 
      DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  (SELECT
      PCR.repdte
      FROM 
      All_Reports_19930330_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
      PCR) AS Quarter,
   (SELECT 
     Round(AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr))
     FROM All_Reports_19930330_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios 
     as PCR) AS NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
   (SELECT sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int))
     FROM 
    'All_Reports_19930330_Deposits_Based_on_the_Dollars250,000
     _Reporting_Threshold' AS LD) AS 
     DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to write a generator that yields date strings in three month increments from a given date string to the present.  We can store the initial date in a `datetime` object, using that to generate the new date strings at every step, and keep the dates from moving past the present.  Then we can use [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) to find the last days of the given months.

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

def dates_from(start):
    date  = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y%m%d")
    today = datetime.today()
    while date < today:
        yield date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        month = date.month + 3
        year = date.year
        if month > 12:
            year += 1
            month -= 12
        _, day = monthrange(year, month)
        date = datetime(year, month, day)
```

Then we can use string formatting to inject this value into a template string

```
sql_template = """\
SELECT 
  (SELECT
      PCR.repdte
      FROM 
      All_Reports_{0}_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
      PCR) AS Quarter,
  (SELECT 
      Round(AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr))
      FROM 
      All_Reports_{0}_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as 
      PCR) AS NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
  (SELECT sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int))
      FROM 
     'All_Reports_{0}_Deposits_Based_on_the_Dollars250,000
     _Reporting_Threshold' AS LD) AS 
     DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k"""

queries = map(sql_template.format, dates_from("19921231"))
output_string = "\nUNION ALL\n".join(queries)
```